# What is a Snake Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Snake Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Snake Words™ | Not Snake Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| FOUR | EIGHT |
| KNIGHT | KNAVE |
| LIZARD | SNAKE |
| MONDAY | FRIDAY |
| MOTHER | MOM |
| OMEGA | BETA |
| PEACH | LEMON |
| PLOUGHERS | FLOWERS |
| REACTION | REPLY |
| RETHINK | THINKER |
| STACK | OVERFLOW |
| SILVER | BRONZE |
| TANGO | FOXTROT |
| THIS | THAT |
| THUNDER | STORM |
| TRUMP | PENCE |
| VARYING | STEADY |
| WEALTH | WEALTHY |
| WHITE | BLACK |

CSV version:

```
Snake Words™,Not Snake Words™
FOUR,EIGHT
KNIGHT,KNAVE
LIZARD,SNAKE
MONDAY,FRIDAY
MOTHER,MOM
OMEGA,BETA
PEACH,LEMON
PLOUGHERS,FLOWERS
REACTION,REPLY
RETHINK,THINKER
STACK,OVERFLOW
SILVER,BRONZE
TANGO,FOXTROT
THIS,THAT
THUNDER,STORM
TRUMP,PENCE
VARYING,STEADY
WEALTH,WEALTHY
WHITE,BLACK
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Snake Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Snake Words™, many more exist.

**Bonus question:** What is the longest Snake Word™ in the English language?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can call these "Snake Words" if the word "Snake" is not a "Snake Word"!!

Comment: @GordonK: "Anagram" is not an anagram of anything. "Palindrome" is not a palindrome. "Indescribable" is a descriptor.

Comment: @Flater I think there are a few people who might disagree with your first statement https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mr+agana&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVytbGlYfZAhVBI8AKHdukBU8Q_AUICygC&biw=1348&bih=622

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A Snake word is one that:

> When you place the letters on a standard QWERTY keyboard, you can construct a path through adjacent letter keys to spell the full word without intersections.

Examples:

> PLOUGHERS: PLOiUytGHbvcxzawERdS
>  RETHINK: REdfTgHuIjNmK
>  WEALTHY: WEdsAzxcvbnmkLoiuyTgHY -collides at Y
>  FLOWERS: FghjkLOiuytrdxzaWER -collides at R

Comment: +1 but `WEALTHY` is possible if number keys are allowed. You should clarify that the path must be through adjacent *letter* keys.

Comment: Good point, edited to clarify

Comment: For _descrying_ \* out loud! I've _outgnawed_ my dictionary and it seems 9-letter words such as "ploughers" are already the best we can get. _Casefying_ _plighters_! _Longheads_, all of them, with _filmcards_ for _loinguards_! #@$! [_redacting_. I'll be _rewashing_ my mouth.]  (\* Yeah, I know it doesn't mean crying.)

Comment: @MOehm: Uhhh.... but *loinguards* is 10 letters.

Comment: @gnovice: Oh, cool! My dictionary only had _loinguard_, but the plural seems to work, too.

Answer (score 5):

I [EDITED: *no longer*] think a Snake Word is one

> that, if you locate its letters on a standard QWERTY keyboard and draw lines between successive pairs, produces a non-self-intersecting trace

but that condition seems to hold for a substantial majority of the Snake Words listed and for none of the non-Snake-Words listed, which seems like it can't be pure coincidence.

It fails for the following Snake Words in the table: PLOUGHERS, RETHINK, SILVER, THIS, TRUMP.

I wondered whether

> the right condition might involve some QWERTY-like layout that isn't quite QWERTY. Levieux's name suggests trying AZERTY but that also doesn't work.

... Aha, looks like Sconibulus has it, and I was indeed kinda on the right lines.